# Shutdown my Solo 401(K) plan and form 5310

Tags: united-states, 401k, irs, solo-401k

I recently shutdown my Solo 401(K) plan at E*Trade. I plan to file form 5500EZ. I have distributed the money to a traditional IRA and a Roth IRA. None of the money went into another 401(K) plan.

Do I need to file form 5310? I believe the answer is no, but I want to be sure.

I am in the United States.

Here is some more information:

For more information about form 5310 you can look here:
https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i5310.pdf
https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/terminating-a-retirement-plan

I believe form 5310 is required when two companies merge and each company has its own 401(K). I also believe that it is required when you terminate a plan and require the assets of the plan be distributed to another 401(K) plan.

Recall that when a 401(K) plan is terminated, all participants must be vested.

However, I am not sure of my facts that is why I asked the question.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that you would need to? I have a Solo 401(k) but I have only heard of the need to file Form 5500-EZ.